# Работа с массивом в pascal.abc

Tags: массивы, pascalabc.net

Задача следующая:

Заполнить массив 100 случайными целыми числами от 1 до 10

И дальше нужно выполнить ещё 3 условия:

1. заполнить так, чтобы всех элементов было поровну
2. Найти самую длинную цепочку чётных элементов
3. Найти самую длинную возрастающую цепочку чётных элементов идущих последовательно (например, 2 4 6 8 10)

Я написал код, чтобы можно было задать массив, но с условиями проблемка:

```
const n=100;
  var a:array[1..n] of byte;
     i:byte;
     с:integer;
  begin
    randomize;
    с:=1;
      for i:=1 to 100 do
      begin
        a[i]:=1+random(10);
        write(a[i]:3);
          if odd(i) then
          с:=с*a[i];
      end;
writeln;
end.
```

Comment: Вот только Ваш код не обеспечивает условия "заполнить так, чтобы всех элементов было поровну".

Answer (score 0):

```
##
var a := new integer[100];
for var i := 0 to 9 do
  a[10 * i:10 * (i + 1)] := 10 * |i + 1|;
a.Shuffle; // перемешиваем случайным образом
a.Println;
// дойдем до первого четного элемента
var i := 0;
while a[i].IsOdd do
  i += 1;
// начальные установки (мы нашли один четный элемент)
var (L, LMax, LAsc, LMaxAsc) := (1, 1, 1, 1);
// основная часть
repeat
  i += 1;
  if a[i].IsEven then begin
    L += 1;
    if a[i] > a[i - 1] then
      LAsc += 1
    else
      (LAsc, LMaxAsc) := (1, Max(LMaxAsc, LAsc))
  end
  else
    (L, LMax, LAsc, LMaxAsc) := (0, Max(L, LMax), 0, Max(LAsc, LMaxAsc))  
until i = a.High;
(LMax, LMaxAsc) := (Max(L, LMax), Max(LAsc, LMaxAsc));
Write(NewLine, LMax, ' ', LMaxAsc)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]